# IDP Initialized SSO, how to configure when dont have the pwd for PrivateKey

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using spring-security saml extension to implement the IDP initiated SSO for my application. I am using https protocol and signature/encryption is ON. I dont need SLO/SP-Initiated SSO.

On the transport layer's encryption/decryption (because using HTTPS protocol), I am fine as My web container (SP one) is going to take care of the decryption part. And this certificate could be different then SP's certifiate.

At the SP end, I need the IDP's public key to verify the signature on SAMLAuthResponse Msg, which I have as part of the IDP's metadata file...so no issues here.

Couple of qns:

1. For decryption of the SAMLAuthResponse Msg, Do I need SP's
   certificate's private key?
2. And If I need the private key, how to
   create the bean definition for keyManager when I have the jks file,
   jks-pwd, alias, but no pwd for privatekey? Can I pass the empty string (as "") in the password field in the alias-password value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip usage of private key in this case. You can find detail on how to use Spring SAML without keystore in the [manual chapter 8.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/security.html#configuration-key-management):

> In case your application doesn't need to create digital signatures
>   and/or decrypt incoming messages, it is possible to use an empty
>   implementation of the keystore which doesn't require any JKS file -
>   org.springframework.security.saml.key.EmptyKeyManager. This can be the
>   case for example when using only IDP-Initialized single sign-on.
>   Please note that when using the EmptyKeyManager some of Spring SAML
>   features will be unavailable. This includes at least SP-initialized
>   Single Sign-on, Single Logout, usage of additional keys in
>   ExtendedMetadata and verification of metadata signatures. Use the
>   following bean in order to initialize the EmptyKeyManager:

```
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.EmptyKeyManager"/>
```